# Build customized RPM for sqlite3 with rtree extension

Tags: linux, sqlite, rpm, rhel, rpmbuild

I have the case that I'm using the sqlite3 database which is installed on the Red Hat Linux distribution.

Additionally to the sqlite3 database I need the rtree extension. By default this is not supported but could easily recompiled by a developer to get the rtree support.

To avoid some installation problems with the operation team I'm looking for an RPM which has the rtree support. In a good case I must only upgrade sqlite3 with the `rpm` command.

Does an RPM package for Linux exists which supports sqlite3 with the rtree extension?
If not could I build an RPM package with sqlite3 and rtree extension? If yes, how?

Comment: It is recommended to compile SQLite into your program. Why do you think that an RPM is better?

Comment: That's a fair question. I was convinced to go this way because I'm using a HttpServlet for a Tomcat6. The database driver was using the Linux sqlite3 database. I will evaluate your idea.